# What's complexity of this algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, code-complexity

I'm learning how to find algorithm complexity and I can't figure out what's the complexity of this algorithm. Could someone explain to me how to get the answer?

```
void algorithm(int a, int b) {
    while (a >= b) {
        int x = a - b;
        for (int i = 0; i <= x; i++) {
            std::cout << "complexity of this algorithm?";
        }
        a = x;
    }
}
```

Please any input is welcome. This is what I have so far:

[image: This is what I have so far]

Comment: What scenario are you considering in your question? best time? average? worst?

Comment: best & worst, if there is a best...I,m not sure if the best case would be different from the worst case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The complexity is (a^2/b)

As I described in the image, you need to sum up all "x", then you will get the complexity.

```
in summation part for (-b -2b -3b - ... -nb) you can write :
[![enter image description here][1]][1]-b (1+2+...)
so this is -b*(n(n+1)/2)
```

[summation_part_definition_link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF)

[image]

So in the end, if "a" and "b" were for the same order then the result is :

> O(c) = 0 (c is numeric)

this means complexity is in numeric order. but if "a" was for upper order then the result is :

> O((a^2)/b)

Comment: @ItsNotMyFault don't you agree with this solution?

Comment: I don't understand most of the simplification of your summation and since I don't know the answer I can't really agree with anything.
Which Summation rule do you use here ? ( I don't understand your reprensation of the summation)
Is the Xi some sort of substitution?

Comment: @ItsNotMyFault check this link and my edits again. 
[link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF)

Comment: When I simplify the sommation (same sommation you have, but I replace your Xi with : (a - b*i + 1) => which is the result of my inner sommation.
My inner sommation is (because of OmG, he said that since a changes it should be in the parameters of the sum) : sum_j=0^(a - j*b) 1
and then I get (a^2)/b + a/2 + a/b.
But I agree with your complexity result because of the maximum  rule.

Answer (score 2):

As `a` is modified, you should have it in parameters of the sum:

```
(1) x = a - b  // first iteration
(2) x = a - 2b // second iteration
(3) x = a - 3b
...
```

if `a = k * b`, the outer loop iterates `k` times. Hence, the final complexity is:

```
(a - b) + (a - 2b) + ... + (a - (k-1) b) = 
(k-1) b + (k-2) b + ... + b = k * (k-1) * b/2
```

As you have mentioned
[image]
, time complexity is
[image]
.

Comment: @UweJ, you realise that that's effectively the same complexity as given here? only OmG has been a little more precise. (in complexity we often don't care about ceilings/floors, etc, but in this case if `a` and `b` grow *together* then then ceiling remains relevant even in complexity theory).